# Can you control a unit outside your home with JavaScript? For example, shut down a Raspberry Pi 3 with the button "Shut down" on a web page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, raspberry-pi

A few years ago I made a UI using 7-inch touchscreen connected to Raspberry Pi 3.

I had a digital button "shut down" and it worked perfectly to send a message to the Raspberry with Java (see the code below).

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo shutdown -h now");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I want to shut down a Raspberry Pi 3 with a "Shut down" button on a web page using JavaScript. So I assume I need to give privileges to the web server and after that send this message `sudo shutdown -h now` to the Raspberry. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Node.js if you want to use server-side JavaScript.
Something like this:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
const { exec } = require("child_process");

// when navigating to your http://<yourdomain>/shutdown
app.get('/shutdown', function (req, res) {
  exec("sudo shutdown -h now", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the question but I am new to Node.js do I need to wrap this example into a class or function like this: "sendMessage = function(req, res) {}"? What do I need to do from the Raspberry side to receive this message?

Comment: I understand you want to call this from a webpage. So you need to create a route in your Node.js backend that will handle a request to run this command.

Comment: Added an example with a route. It should get your in the correct direction.

Comment: Will this work when I open http://<yourdomain>/shutdown on any device?

Comment: I assume that If I want to connect without using my local network, so I need to open some ports on my router.